# Method of JDialog returns null

Tags: java, swing, null, jdialog

Question: Why is the String `name` always null?

This is how I create the dialog `Add` in my class:

```
public void init (){
    try {
        Add dialog = new Add();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE );
        //dialog.add(comp)
        dialog.setModal(true) ;
        //dialog.setModalityType(dialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here I get the value from the user:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    name =  textField.getText();
    System.out.println(name);
    setVisible(false);
 }
```

The method to get user's value from another class:

```
public String Get(){
    return name;
}
```

Here I try to use the value, but `name` is always `null`:

```
Add l = new Add();
l.init();
String name = l.Get();
```

Comment: Have you registered listener against user operation? if yes, Are you checking for that string after event or before event?

Comment: yes (actually is an ok button ) and I'm checking  the string after the event

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. Your last snippet contradicts your first snippet: the first snippet shows that to create and display a dialog, you create an instance of Add, then make it modal, then visible. Whereas the last one shows that you create an Add, call some init() method on it. If the init() method is the one from your first snippet, you're using an Add to create **another** Add. Why?

Comment: the last snippet is in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem you created `Add` instance two times. Remove `Add dialog = new Add();` in `init()` method, it will work.

```
public void init (){
    try {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE );
        //dialog.add(comp)
        this.setModal(true) ;
        //dialog.setModalityType(dialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);
        this.setVisible(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```